# How to create a custom installation USB Live Flash Drive OS image file?

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-installation

Step 1: I would like to install UBUNTU on a platform and then customize this installation with programs, printer setups, users, etc.

Step 2: Once this platform's installation is customized to the required preferences, I would like to create and install image/copy on a USB Flash Live Drive that I could use to duplicate this custom installation on other platforms.

Step 3: In addition, to be able to install the customized UBUNTU to other platforms, I would like to be able to run the customized UBUNTU OS on the USB Live Flash session before installation to check compatibility, and once I am ready, I just click the "Install UBUNTU" on the desktop to install.

***Is this possible?   What would be the steps to create this flash drive?***

Thank you for the help -

Comment: I found this older [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339874/create-a-customized-ubuntu-live-usb) that seems to has some other steps.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to create an OEM system according to this link. This way, the systems can be given individual identities (good in a local network), and individual user IDs and password during the final installation.

The idea is to make a compressed image or cloned copy of the tweaked installed system, and clone it to USB drives, or internal drives. If you avoid proprietary drivers, such a system is quite portable between PC computers. And I think this is much easier than to create an ISO file with a working live session and a working installer.

See these links

[Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)

[Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

(The server with the compressed image files is temporarily down, but you are mainly interested in the method, which is described in the links to the Ubuntu help pages.)

You can also use Clonezilla to create (and restore from) the compressed image.

[clonezilla.org](http://clonezilla.org)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a Custom Live CD, take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).